# How do I know the website is CDN enabled?

Tags: cloudflare

How can I know if a website is CDN enabled? If it is using the Cloudfare CDN, is it possible to disable the cache for specific URL?

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Comment: `dig example.com`; put the resulting IP through `nslookup`, see who owns it. Bypassing it depends; are you the owner of the domain? Or looking to evade someone else's protections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ping` to check if a domain is under a CDN, for example:

```bash
$ ping chat.openai.com

Pinging chat.openai.com.cdn.cloudflare.net [104.18.3.161] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 104.18.3.161: bytes=32 time=133ms TTL=54
Reply from 104.18.3.161: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=54
Reply from 104.18.3.161: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=54
Reply from 104.18.3.161: bytes=32 time=129ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 104.18.3.161:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 129ms, Maximum = 133ms, Average = 130ms
```

Here we found a `chat.openai.com.cdn.cloudflare.net` domain. Which means `chat.openai.com` is a CNAME. This method works in most cases